# Should GCC/Clang optimize this redundant load via an array of restrict-qualified pointers?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, restrict-qualifier

I am looking into optimizations permitted for a compiler by adding the C99 *restrict* type qualifier to the type parameter of an array.

For example, consider the function *f* below:

```
int f(int* restrict a[2]) {
    *(a[0]) = 10;
    *(a[1]) = 11;
    return *(a[0]);
}
```

It takes as argument a two-element array *a* of restrict pointers to integers. The function stores `10` into the object `a[0]` points to and `11` into the object `a[1]` points to. Finally, it returns the value of the object `a[0]` points to.

Because the pointers `a[0]` and `a[1]` are restrict qualified, I would assume a compiler has enough information to perform the typical optimization of not loading from `a[0]` again, but instead directly returning `10` (because the write to `a[1]` could not have changed the object `a[0]` points to if the program has defined behavior).

So if the optimization would take place on "C-code level", the function would then become:

```
int f(int* restrict a[2]) {
    *(a[0]) = 10;
    *(a[1]) = 11;
    return 10;
}
```

However, both GCC and Clang (I tried several versions, among which the latest on Godbolt), do not perform this optimization (when compiling with -O3).

The assembly for X86 that GCC13.2 emits is

```
f:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rdi+8]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], 10
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdx], 11
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
        ret
```

As one can see, a reload from register `[rax]` is performed instead of just moving `10` into `eax`.

A similar program where the pointers are passed as separate arguments instead of an array of pointers does exhibit the expected optimization for both compilers:

```
int g(int* restrict p, int* restrict q) {
    *p = 10;
    *q = 11;
    return *p;
}
```

Is compiled into:

```
g:
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], 10
        mov     eax, 10
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsi], 11
        ret
```

---

Do I misunderstand the semantics of a restrict qualified pointer as the type parameter of an array, or is the expected optimization simply too hard for aforementioned compilers?

Comment: No compilers on the market seems to analyze parameters particularly in-depth, to the point where they care if a parameter contains an item which in itself is restrict-qualified.

Comment: @Lundin the second code block indicates the optimization "on C-code level" I would expect to be performed by a compiler on the first code block. It isn't an example I expect to be optimized itself (so in the link you provided, change `10` with `*(a[0])`).

Comment: Ach, my bad, I pasted the wrong snippet. Nevermind!

Comment: Hypothesis about why the compilers optimize the `int * restrict p, int * restrict q` case but not the `int * restrict a[2]` case: They allow for a possibility that `*a[i]` aliases `a[i]` even though such aliasing does not conform to the C standard’s aliasing rules. In other words, `*a[1] = 11;` could change the value of `a[0]`, making `a[0]` point to somewhere other than where the 10 was stored.

Comment: Thanks Eric, this actually makes the most sense for me from all the given answers (feel free to move it into a separate answer). I checked to see what GCC does: https://godbolt.org/z/W5G1s3zzv with `-O3` it will "optimize" `f` to return `10`, whereas without enabled optimizations the program segfaults as it attempts to store to memory address `11`. Do you think the optimized version is in accordance with the restrict semantics from the standard?

Comment: @Ties I don't think that example is related, since upon -O3 gcc simply drops the whole function including the dirty cast and de-referencing that leads to UB. In your restrict examples it didn't do that, because there were other side effects. Now if you make it `extern int x` the example goes haywire, only storing 10 into x and then returning 10. Too much UB to make any sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

This optimization cannot be done and your second example is invalid (as forgot about one level of indirection).

1. Even if you restrict both pointers when you access it as an array you will not break the contract with the compiler if access via the second element will not modify the the first one. So it has to be loaded again.

```
int f(int* restrict * restrict a) {
    *(a[0]) = 10;
    *(a[1]) = 11;
    return *(a[0]);
}

//this function is to illustrate the issue
void foo(void)
{
    int a;
    int *b[2] = {&a,&a};
    f(b);
}
```

2. Your pointer example needs to use double pointers not the single ones.

```
int g(int* restrict * restrict p, int* restrict * restrict q) {
    **p = 10;
    **q = 11;
    return **p;
}
```

This will generate the optimized code as you can't access the object referenced by `*p` using `*q` without breaking the promise you give to the compiler.

```
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rdi]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], 10
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsi]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], 11
        mov     eax, 10
        ret
```

Comment: *Your pointer example needs to use double pointers not the single ones.*  I'm not sure how this applies.  Could you explain it more?   [`void *memcpy(void * restrict s1, const void * restrict s2, size_t n);`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.2.1) seems to be closer to what the question is providing as an example of where the compiler should optimize, and the contract *would* be broken if the pointers alias, as in your `int *b[2] = {&a,&a};` example.

Comment: @AndrewHenle 1. First example has more than indirections than the second one. It is not possible to compare. 2. It is not. You access via passed pointer as promised.

Comment: There's no obvious reason why pointer-to-pointer must be needed. Yes in the OP's case the pointers themselves may be modified between accesses, sure. This doesn't solve the problem either https://godbolt.org/z/3bKEdr7GK and there's no obvious reason why.

Comment: @Ties what is your comment?

Comment: @Lundin it is exactly the same reason as I stated. The comparison does not change it

Comment: But regardless are local pointers which are guaranteed not to alias. I don't know why latest gcc manages to optimize your pointer-to-pointer version, clang does not.

Comment: > "Even if you restrict both pointers when you access it as an array you will not break the contract with the compiler if access via the second element will not modify the the first one. So it has to be loaded again."   Could you elaborate on this a bit more? Because both `a[0]` and `a[1]` are used to access the same object (whilst not based on each other) *and* the object is modified, the standard says that the program you provided has undefined behavior, right? Or how would you argue that the contract isn't broken?

Comment: @Ties no, it is not right. It is very well defined and it is the reason why it reads the memory again.

Comment: Look at this: https://godbolt.org/z/ExEa6M1xh. The only difference is literally a load from `rdi + 8` vs a load from `rsi`. clang fails to optimize both versions, gcc optimizes only `g`. None of it makes sense, this is all in the category of "missed micro-optimizations".

Comment: @Lundin clang misses in `g`. `f` is optimized correctly

Comment: @gulpr the place where b is assigned the aliasing pointers itself is defined, but I would argue that the undefined behavior occurs at `*(a[1]) = 11;`, because it is a second access within the scope of `f` via another restrict pointer. If I am wrong, could you point me to a specific part of the standard (6.7.3.1) that justifies why the program has defined behavior? Tyvm!

Comment: @gulpr No, it clearly is not. `a` may not be modified by any outside source and besides that's irrelevant for a function with 1 parameter. `p1` is local and what it points at is clearly not going to be modified between accesses since it is not `volatile`.

Comment: @Ties it is not recursive or iterative. The standard considers only the pointer itseld, not underlaying pointers

Comment: @gulpr ahh, so you say that the array _a_ is no instance of what is described in the first bullet point of section 6.7.3.1, right? "*Let D be a declaration of an ordinary identifier that provides a means of designating an
object P as a restrict-qualified pointer to type T.*"  And then you say that _a_ is not an instance of such an ordinary identifier?

Comment: @Ties I think I was quite clear.

Comment: The first sentence of paragraph 1 is an uninformative truism. Maybe it is a typo? It says that if access via the second element (`a[1]`) will not modify the first one (meaning the object pointed to by `a[0]`, hence `*a[0]`), that will not break the contract (about `restrict`). That is trivially true because `restrict` is about asserting that certain things will not access the same object, so accessing different objects never violates the `restrict` restrictions. But this sentence is used as a condition for the next sentence: “So it has to be loaded again.” And that does not follow…

Comment: … If `*(a[1]) = 11;` is known not to modify `*(a[0])`, there is no need to load `*a[0]` again. This needs correction or clarification. And the `foo` example presented shows a case in which `a[0]` and `a[1]` point to the same object, the `a` inside `foo`. So that is a case where modifying `*a[1]` does modify `*a[0]`, which is not illustrative of that first sentence, which is about `*a[1]` not modifying `*a[0]`.